# What is the fastest way of converting an array of floats to string?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

What is the fastest way of converting an array of floats into string in C#?

If my array contains this `{ 0.1, 1.1, 1.0, 0.2 }`

Then I want each entry to converted to a string with value separated by a white space, i.e.  `"0.1 1.1 1.0 0.2"`

Comment: Can you describe the result you expect?

Comment: What's does 'fastest' mean? Runtime performance (which target?), less lines of code, most readable code, etc...

Comment: Just need something that makes me avoid loops

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would go for the most readable `string.Join` which also should have sufficient performance in most cases. Unless there is a real issue, I would not run my own:

```
float[] values = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
string s = string.Join(" ", values);
```

It might be that I misread your question, so in case you want an enumeration of `string` go with the other answers.

Comment: Probably, it will just call `float.ToString()` for each element in the array

Comment: Isn't compiling. Says "Join" has some invalid arguments.

Comment: @abatishchev: Yes, it will, and then it uses a string builder to concatenate the elements. If you need specific formatting then your answer offers all possibilities.

Comment: @Wajih: Sorry, I forgot to check it, but my solution only works with .NET 4.0.

Comment: this answer is readable. The 'checked' answer is not.

Comment: @Wajih: If you need it to work in older versions of .NET then just do `string s = string.Join(" ", values.Select(f => f.ToString()).ToArray())`

Answer (score 8):

To be more explicit, call `float.ToString()` manually and then `string.Join()` to separate each result with a space:

```
var array = new float[] { 0.1, 1.1, 1.0, 0.2 };
string result = String.Join(" ", array.Select(f => f.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

btw,

in .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 there only single `String.Join(string, string[])`

but in .NET 4.0 there is also `String.Join<T>(string, IEnumerable<T>)`

@0xA3 uses method from .NET 4.0. Mine too. So for earlier versions use `array.Select(..).ToArray()`

Comment: This seems to be the most complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
var floatsAsString = yourFloatArray.Select(f => f.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
float[] arr = { 1.0f, 2.1f };
var str = arr.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

or use `rray.ConvertAll`

```
public static string FloatFToString(float f)
{
    return f.ToString(); 
}

float[] a = { 1.0f, 2.1f };
var res = Array.ConvertAll(a, new Converter<float, string>(FloatFToString));
```

Answer (score -2):

I like approach with using [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) method:

```
float[] array = new float[] { .1f, .2f, .3f, .4f, .5f };
string s = array.AsEnumerable().Aggregate<float, string, string>("", (a, e) => a += string.Format(" {0}", e), r => r.Trim());
```

Works fast.

Comment: Using `String.Concat` and `String.Format` definitely is very inefficient

Comment: @abatishchev So, what is better way?

Comment: Mine or @0xA3's way, I guess. Because `String.Join` uses `StringBuilder` internally that's much more efficient because of strings immutability in .NET.

Comment: @abatishchev Thanks for info, i didn't know that String.Join uses StringBuilder internally.

Comment: You can investigate such things using [RedGate .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Comment: Also as far as `Array` has not its own method `Aggregate` there is no need to call `AsEnumerable` because `Array` is already `IEnumerable`